# Null reference exception in custom code activity

Tags: dynamics-crm

I run into null reference exception when I execute code activity on server.

```
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context) {          
        //IWorkflowContext executionContext = context.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
        //IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = context.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        //IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(executionContext.UserId);

        //XmlDocument doc = GetEmbeddedXMLDocument();
        //XDocument xDoc = doc.ToXDocument();                       

        ////context.SetValue<bool>(IsExist, false);

        ////string ent = context.GetValue(InputEnt);
        ////string searchAtrib = context.GetValue(SearchAttrib);
        //////string condition = context.GetValue(Condition);
        ////string attribValue = context.GetValue(AttribValue);

        ////QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute(ent);
        ////query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new String[] {searchAtrib});
        ////query.Attributes.Add(searchAtrib);
        ////query.Values.Add(attribValue);

        ////EntityCollection retrived = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        ////if (retrived.Entities.Count>0) {
        ////    context.SetValue<bool>(IsExist, true);
        ////}

        //var docData = new JObject();
        //docData = ParseDataStringToObject(context);            

        //SysColl.List<DataContainer> entityes = new SysColl.List<DataContainer>();
        //FillEntityes(xDoc, entityes);
        //entityes.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList<DataContainer>();

        //CreateEntityesInMemo(entityes,docData, service, context);
    }
```

calling function. Ordinary XMLHttpRequest behind the scene.

```
var result = Process.callAction("kr_ParseInitialData",
        [{
            key: "InputEnt",
            type: Process.Type.String,
            value: json_object
        }],
        function () {
            //createAttachment(attachmentData);
            debugger
            clearFormControls();
            alert(result);
        },
        function (errInfo) {
            alert(errInfo);
        });
```

As you can see, I comment everything, but still get the same exception. In Debug code works fine. Any ideas?
Sincerely.

Comment: you should post the stacktrace, as it is not clear from your question which line throws the exception. You pasted some javascript code, but you did not explain what has this javascript has to do with your Custom Workflow Activity

Answer (score 1):

It's seems it was a CRM bug. I unreg and reg the same dll, nothing change in code. Now it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong method to call CallActivity. According to Process.js Documentation: https://processjs.codeplex.com/ you should use:

```
Process.callWorkflow("4AB26754-3F2F-4B1D-9EC7-F8932331567A", 
Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(),
function () {
    alert("Workflow executed successfully");
},
function () {
    alert("Error executing workflow");
});
```

If you want to use Custom Action, then first create custom action with Input/Output paramerters you want in CRM. Then create Plugin Project (Template) in VS. Then register this plugin at your Action (like this http://www.powerobjects.com/2016/04/11/setting-output-parameters-in-plugins-for-custom-actions/). Then you can call this action from JS using Process.callAction

P.S. Pay attention that Action have "Target" paramenter by the default, don`t forget to add it

Comment: No. I'm calling a Global Action, not Workflow.

Comment: Then you should create Plugin project, not Workflow Porject with such structure
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            var factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            var service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);